# How can I convert a date column in character format "yy-mmm" to a usable quarterly format for ggplot visualization?

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series

I want to perform an analysis of property prices across segments on a quarterly basis (x-axis) from 2016 Jan to 2019 Jan.

However the column of data I would like to use is in a month format (`c("19-Jan", "19-Feb", "19-Mar", "19-Apr",..."19-Dec")`, that is a "yy-mmm" character format.

I wanted the whole column of data to be converted from `"19-Jan"` to a date format as such `c("Qtr 1 - 2016", "Qtr 2 - 2017", ... "Qtr 3 - 2018")` etc.

How can I convert the column containing character values of "19-Jan" to a quarter format?

I have attached my raw date format data in a google link since it has over 56,000 rows:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cynVkZv0aJRjwFgvVzlSRG7G-6t96cAgXOZMTJdPkC8/edit#gid=80649901

Here is my previous graph with yearly analysis (which I want to convert to quarterly):

[image]

This is my code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

URA_data <- read.csv('URAdata.csv')

options(scipen=999)

Plotly<-URA_data %>%
  mutate(Year = 2000 + as.integer(substring(Date.of.Sale, 1, 2))) %>%
  filter(Type.of.Sale %in% "Resale" & Type %in% "Condominium")%>%
  group_by(Year,Market.Segment ) %>%
  summarise(Price = mean(Price....))%>%
  ggplot(aes(Year, Price, color = Market.Segment)) + geom_line()+ geom_point()+
  labs(color="Segments")+
  ggtitle("Median Property Prices by Market Segments ")+
  xlab("Year")+ylab("Price (Median)")+
  theme(
    plot.title=element_text(color="red",size=14,face="bold.italic",hjust=0.5),
    axis.title.x=element_text(color="blue",size=14,face="bold"),
    axis.title.y=element_text(color="green",size=14,face="bold")
  )


library(plotly)

Graph<-ggplotly(Plotly)
Graph
```

Answer (score 2):

The `zoo` package has a `as.yearqtr` function. You could use that to convert your months to quarters. The `format =`  argument allows you to define the format of your month data. You can use `zoo::scale_x_yearqtr` to improve the x-axis formatting

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)
URA_data %>%
  mutate(Quarter = as.yearqtr(Date.of.Sale, format = "%y-%b")) %>%
  filter(Type.of.Sale %in% "Resale" & Type %in% "Condominium")%>%
  group_by(Quarter,Market.Segment ) %>%
  summarise(Price = mean(Price....))%>%
  ggplot(aes(Quarter, Price, color = Market.Segment)) + geom_line()+ geom_point()+
  scale_x_yearqtr(breaks = seq(from = as.yearqtr("2016-1"), to = as.yearqtr("2018-3"), by = 0.25),
                  lim = as.yearqtr(c("2016-1","2018-3"))) +
  labs(color="Segments") + ggtitle("Median Property Prices by Market Segments ")+
  xlab("Quarter")+ylab("Price (Median)")+
  theme(plot.title=element_text(color="red",size=14,face="bold.italic",hjust=0.5),
        axis.title.x=element_text(color="blue",size=14,face="bold"),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1),
        axis.title.y=element_text(color="green",size=14,face="bold"))
```

[image]

Download and fix data:

```
library(gsheet)
URA_data <- gsheet::gsheet2tbl("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cynVkZv0aJRjwFgvVzlSRG7G-6t96cAgXOZMTJdPkC8/edit#gid=80649901")
URA_data <- URA_data %>%
  mutate(Type.of.Sale = `Type of Sale`, Date.of.Sale = `Date of Sale`, 
         Market.Segment = `Market Segment`, Price.... = `Price ($)`)
```

Comment: Would be helping to display the x-axis in a vertical manner allow for more quarter-year x-axis to appear. I think for a better representation, can I also take out the first quarter of 2019 to only display from 2016 Qtr 1 to 2018 Qtr  4

Comment: @ChuaSYang I have edited my answer to address your requests. Please make further requests as a new question.